# How to change a list item from a string to a float in Python3

Tags: list, types, python-3.x, tuples

```
list=['word','2']

print(type(list[0]))

<class 'str'>

print(type(list[0]))

<class 'str'>
```

## I want list[0] to remain a string while list[1] becomes a float.

Sorry If i'm not posting this in the correct format I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
list[1] = float(list[1])
```

as shown in the following transcript:

```
>>> list=['word','2']

>>> type(list[0]) ; type(list[1])
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>

>>> list ; list[1] = float(list[1]) ; list
['word', '2']
['word', 2.0]

>>> type(list[0]) ; type(list[1])
<type 'str'>
<type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reassign the element:

```
list[1] = float(list[1])
```